# AWS - Connect to RDS via EC2 tunnel

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, psycopg2, amazon-vpc

My RDS is in a VPC, so it has a private IP address. I can connect my RDS database instance from my local computer with pgAdmin using SSH tunneling via EC2 Elastic IP.

Now I want to connect to the database instance in my code in python. How can I do that?

Comment: The same way? Use an ssh tunnel. Just manage `ssh` from Python. Hundreds of examples out there. Or give it a public IP. Or use a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Point your python code to the same address and port you're using for the tunnelling.

If you're not sure check the pgAdmin destination in the configuration and just copy it.